# Python & Pandas: Find a dict within a list according to a key's value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list which look like this:

```
dict_list = [{'angle': 5.0,
              'basic_info': '111',
              'x': [1,2,3,4],
              'y': [3,2,1,4],},
            {'angle': 25.0,
              'basic_info': '111',
              'x': [1,2,3,4],
              'y': [3,1,5,2],},
            {'angle': 3.0,
              'basic_info': '111',
              'x': [1,2,3,4],
              'y': [1,1,4,1],},]
```

I want to get the dict angle 25, how can I do it?

---

UPDATE:

After playing a while with Pandas, I find this might be possible

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_list)
temp = df.query("(angle ==25 )").T.to_dict()[temp.keys()[0]]
temp
```

Returns

```
{'angle': 25.0, 'basic_info': '111', 'x': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'y': [3, 1, 5, 2]}
```

But this is a bit hack.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming each angle in your dictionary is unique and each dictionary contains the key 'angle':

```
df = None
for sub_dict in dict_list:
    if sub_dict['angle'] == 25:
        df = pd.DataFrame({'x': sub_dict['x'], 'y': sub_dict['y']})
        break  # Stops after finding the first matching angle.
if df is not None:
    df.plot(x='x', y='y')
```

[image]

Comment: I have made an UPDATE. I think it looks pretty simple, can you check with that too?

Comment: @cqcn1991 have you tried `df.query('angle == 25').plot(x='x', y='y')`?

Comment: @oldrinb I'm afraid that's not enough. The core problem is about extracting info at a given row. I also need the value to some other works.

Answer (score 0):

The built-in [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) function will do what you want... you just need to feed it a function that determines which objects to keep.  That function below is `has_angle`.

I wrapped `has_angle` in `filter_by_angle`, so I could use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to avoid hard-coding the angle sought.  `filter_by_angle` is a generator function, so it can `yield` any number of matching shapes.

```
import functools


def has_angle(angle, shape):
    # get with default None prevents a KeyError on shapes
    # without angles.
    return shape.get('angle', None) == angle


def filter_by_angle(angle, shapes):
    filter_key = functools.partial(has_angle, angle)
    yield from filter(filter_key, shapes)


def main():
    dict_list = ...  # Same as yours.
    matching_shapes = filter_by_angle(25, dict_list)
    for shape in matching_shapes:
        print(shape)
    return
```

This prints:

```
{'y': [3, 1, 5, 2], 'angle': 25.0, 'x': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'basic_info': '111'}
```

Note that the `yield from` syntax requires Python 3.3 or greater.

Comment: This can be a good alternative for some good programmers. However, I finally hacked this problem with 2 lines with `pandas`.

Comment: @cqcn1991:  I couldn't tell if `pandas` was a requirement, or just something you were trying because you couldn't find a pure Python way.  Since you started with just lists and dicts, I didn't see any need to convert it all to dataframes just to filter it.

Comment: @cqcn1991:  Also, please self-answer your question, so people know it's been solved.

Comment: I think it is not a good answer. Still, I update it in the question.